# Why does Jekyll read some my posts but not build them?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, static-site

Here's the output from `jekyll serve --verbose`. As you can see, Jekyll reads 4 markdown files, but only actually builds 3. `2016-02-31-github-webhooks-node.md` is not built, but also doesn't seem to throw any errors.

```
jekyll serve --verbose
  Logging at level: debug
Configuration file: /home/bryce/_repos/devbryce/devbryce-jekyll/_config.yml
         Requiring: jekyll-paginate
         Requiring: kramdown
            Source: /home/bryce/_repos/devbryce/devbryce-jekyll
       Destination: /home/bryce/_repos/devbryce/devbryce-jekyll/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
           Reading: _posts/2013-12-31-whats-jekyll.md
           Reading: _posts/2016-02-31-github-webhooks-node.md
           Reading: _posts/2014-01-02-introducing-lanyon.md
           Reading: _posts/2014-01-01-example-content.md
         Rendering: _posts/2013-12-31-whats-jekyll.md
  Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2013-12-31-whats-jekyll.md
  Rendering Liquid: _posts/2013-12-31-whats-jekyll.md
  Rendering Markup: _posts/2013-12-31-whats-jekyll.md
         Requiring: kramdown
  Rendering Layout: _posts/2013-12-31-whats-jekyll.md
         Rendering: _posts/2014-01-01-example-content.md
  Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2014-01-01-example-content.md
  Rendering Liquid: _posts/2014-01-01-example-content.md
         Requiring: rouge
  Rendering Markup: _posts/2014-01-01-example-content.md
  Rendering Layout: _posts/2014-01-01-example-content.md
         Rendering: _posts/2014-01-02-introducing-lanyon.md
  Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2014-01-02-introducing-lanyon.md
  Rendering Liquid: _posts/2014-01-02-introducing-lanyon.md
  Rendering Markup: _posts/2014-01-02-introducing-lanyon.md
  Rendering Layout: _posts/2014-01-02-introducing-lanyon.md
         Rendering: 404.html
  Pre-Render Hooks: 404.html
  Rendering Liquid: 404.html
  Rendering Markup: 404.html
  Rendering Layout: 404.html
         Rendering: about.md
  Pre-Render Hooks: about.md
  Rendering Liquid: about.md
  Rendering Markup: about.md
  Rendering Layout: about.md
         Rendering: atom.xml
  Pre-Render Hooks: atom.xml
  Rendering Liquid: atom.xml
  Rendering Markup: atom.xml
  Rendering Layout: atom.xml
         Rendering: index.html
  Pre-Render Hooks: index.html
  Rendering Liquid: index.html
  Rendering Markup: index.html
  Rendering Layout: index.html
                    done in 0.209 seconds.
         Requiring: jekyll-watch
         Requiring: jekyll-paginate
         Requiring: kramdown
           Watcher: Ignoring (?-mix:_config\.yml)
           Watcher: Ignoring (?-mix:_site)
```

The contents of `2016-02-31-github-webhooks-node.md`:

```
---
layout: post
title: Setting up Github Webhooks with your Node app
---

BLEEK BLOOP BLOP
```

For what it's worth, it's the only post I've created on my own. The rest came with the template.

Comment: Use a valid date, otherwise will never be published! :)

Comment: I tried, it will be parsed by Ruby as March, 2nd. However, I wouldn't rely on that being guaranteed behavior, it's a lucky coincidence at best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

February 31st, 2016, is

1. in the future, means that the post will only be published on or after February, 31st, 2016 unless you explicitly tell Jekyll otherwise (by passing `--future` on the commandline or setting it in `_config.yml`)
2. doesn't actually exist, means that it might not get published at all, but will most likely be published on March, 2nd.

Comment: `future: true` in `_config.yml`

Comment: Thanks -- a silly error on my part, although it would be nice if Jekyll threw an error when this happens.

Comment: When what happens? A post has a date from the future? That's just normal usage of Jekyll. You can date a post into the future, and it will be published when that date arrives. Or when a post has a date that doesn't exist? I agree, that should be reported. I guess Jekyll just hands the date to Ruby's date parsing library, which unfortunately allows this.